# Loading .png file with Parcel bundler not working

Tags: parceljs

If I try to include a .png file using Parcel bundler it tells me:

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Cannot find module 'shared/logo.png'`

And this is what I do:

```
import LogoSrc from './logo.png'

export default () => {
  return (<img src={LogoSrc} />)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?